# How do i solve System.Collections.Generic.List does not have difination for ProductID or method for ProductID?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, linq

Below is my view.

```
@model List<EShopperTheme.Domain.Entities.Product>
@using System.Linq
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">

                        <!--Add to Cart Button Here-->
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
                        {
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
                            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" value="Add to cart" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I get above error when i run the application, i added the @using.linq too but it didn't solved the problem i am still getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your hidden to be `@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ProductID)`.

The way you have it, you are trying to access a property that doesn't exist in System.Collections.Generic.List, which is your model, but you need to access the current `item` that you are iterating for the ProductID.

Comment: You are sucha great talent, where did you learn all these about? lol

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick (You have to put @ before your use of item): `<img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { @item.ProductID })" alt="" />`

Replace all use of item with @item inside the foreach loop

Comment: i don't have problem with that i have problem in add to cart

Comment: how does your Product class look like?